# Jewish prayer for our doctor after baby delivery?

Tags: tefilla, medicine, baby-infant

We just had a baby and are scheduled to see our primary care physician very soon.  We know he is religious and would appreciate a short prayer, and we were wondering if there are any Jewish prayers intended to be recited in the company of a close family physician.

We are open to any prayer content, but are just looking for a simple thank you prayer and/or something for the health of the baby (which is of course the doctor's firstly priority).

I can read Hebrew, so no transliteration is necessary, but an English translation would be helpful.

Comment: [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and Mazal Tov! I'd suggest that you [edit your profile](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) and give yourself a name, but I see that you use this ID around the SE network, so I guess it's meaningful to you. I hope you'll look around and find other content of interest, perhaps starting with some of our other [tag:baby-infant] questions.

Answer (score 5):

Mazal Tov!

I suggest [Psalm 128](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16349/jewish/Chapter-128.htm):

> שִׁיר הַמַּעֲלוֹת אַשְׁרֵי כָּל יְרֵא יְהֹוָה הַהֹלֵךְ בִּדְרָכָיו:
>   יְגִיעַ כַּפֶּיךָ כִּי תֹאכֵל אַשְׁרֶיךָ וְטוֹב לָךְ:
>   אֶשְׁתְּךָ | כְּגֶפֶן פֹּרִיָּה בְּיַרְכְּתֵי בֵיתֶךָ בָּנֶיךָ כִּשְׁתִלֵי זֵיתִים סָבִיב לְשֻׁלְחָנֶךָ:
>   הִנֵּה כִי כֵן יְבֹרַךְ גָּבֶר יְרֵא יְהֹוָה:
>   יְבָרֶכְךָ יְהֹוָה מִצִּיּוֹן וּרְאֵה בְּטוּב יְרוּשָׁלִָם כֹּל יְמֵי חַיֶּיךָ:
>   וּרְאֵה בָנִים לְבָנֶיךָ שָׁלוֹם עַל יִשְׂרָאֵל:‏
>
> A song of ascents. Praiseworthy is every man who fears the Lord, who walks in His ways.
>   If you eat the toil of your hands, you are praiseworthy, and it is good for you.
>   Your wife will be as a fruitful vine in the innermost parts of your house; your sons will be like olive shoots around your table.
>   Behold that so will a man who fears the Lord be blessed.
>   May the Lord bless you from Zion, and see the good of Jerusalem all the days of your life.
>   And may you see children [born] to your children, [and see] peace upon Israel.

<sup>(Rabbi A.J. Rosenberg translation, via Chabad.org)</sup>

Aspects of this Psalm that I think fit your situation nicely:

- It's entirely upbeat.
- It's short.
- In referencing "the toil of [a God-fearing person's] hands," it relates to acknowledging the doctor's efforts.
- It refers multiple times to having children as a blessing.
- In particular, I've heard the last verse sung at many celebrations of new babies.

Answer (score 2):

Some people have given their doctors a nice framed copy of A Doctor's Prayer, commonly attributed to Maimonides. [Here's an example](http://www.eichlers.com/maimonides-prayer-blue-framed.html).

Comment: It was almost certainly not actually written by Maimonides.

Comment: @DoubleAA R' Zivotofsky making your point: https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_rambams_physicians_prayer/

Comment: My father has three on the wall in the living room, and likely more in the office.